# How can I get the row-wise sum in this pivot query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following query, which unpivots then repivots data from a table into a format used by some stored procedures that get the same data dynamically:

```
2010-2011   4   3805    953 0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.08399832  79.9034 20.0126 0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2011-2012   81  3867    971 0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1.646676    78.61354    19.73978    0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2012-2013   4   3706    918 0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.08643042  80.07779    19.83578    0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Here is the SQL:

```
            DECLARE @r TABLE (SchoolYearDescription nvarchar(20), StackPosition int, Band_Count real, Band_Percent real)

        INSERT INTO @r
        SELECT y.SchoolYearDescription, rb.StackPosition, ISNULL(SUM(b.Band_Count), 0) AS 'Count', ISNULL(SUM(b.Band_Percent * b.Band_Count)
                    / NULLIF(SUM(b.Band_Count), 0), 0) AS 'Percent'
        FROM RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local g
            INNER JOIN RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands b ON g.pkSummarySubjectLocalID = b.fkSummarySubjectLocalID
            INNER JOIN PerformanceLevelReportBands rb ON b.fkBandID = rb.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID
            RIGHT JOIN MM_SchoolYears y ON g.fkSchoolYearID = y.pkSchoolYearID
            INNER JOIN itot(@strYearIds, N',') tblYearIds ON y.pkSchoolYearId = tblYearIds.number
            INNER JOIN itot(@strDemoCodeIds, N',') tblDemoCodes ON g.fkDemoCommonCodeID = tblDemoCodes.number
            WHERE g.fkRosterSetID = @intRosterSetId
                AND g.fkTestInstanceID = CASE WHEN @intTestInstId = 0 THEN g.fkTestInstanceID ELSE @intTestInstId END
                AND g.fkTestTypeID = @intTestTypeId
                AND g.fkSchoolID = @intSchoolId
                AND g.fkGradeID = @intGradeId
                AND g.fkDepartmentID = @intDeptId
                AND g.fkCourseID = @intCourseId
                AND g.fkPeriodID = @intPeriodId
                AND g.fkTest_SubjectID IN (SELECT id FROM @tempSubs)
                AND rb.fkPerformanceLevelReportID = @intPerfLevelReportId
       GROUP BY y.SchoolYearDescription, rb.StackPosition
       ORDER BY y.SchoolYearDescription, rb.StackPosition

       SELECT * FROM
       (SELECT SchoolYearDescription ,
          CASE 
            WHEN col = 'Band_Count' THEN 'Count_'
            WHEN col = 'Band_Percent' THEN 'Percent_'
            END + CAST(StackPosition as varchar(1)) colName, value
       FROM @r
        UNPIVOT
        (
         value
         FOR col IN ([Band_Count], [Band_Percent])
        ) unpiv) src
        PIVOT
        (MAX(value)
        FOR colName IN (Count_0,Count_1,Count_2,Count_3,Count_4,Count_5,Count_6,Count_7,Count_8,Count_9,
        Percent_0,Percent_1,Percent_2,Percent_3,Percent_4,Percent_5,Percent_6,Percent_7,Percent_8,Percent_9) ) piv

   END
```

How can I add a Count_Include column that is the sum of the Count_0 through Count_9 for each row?

Thanks for any help, this is way beyond the scope of my expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very exciting, but you could just add them:

```
SELECT *
      ,ISNULL(Count_0,0) + ISNULL(Count_1,0) + ISNULL(Count_2,0) + ISNULL(Count_3,0) etc.. AS Count_Include
FROM
       (SELECT SchoolYearDescription ,
          CASE 
            WHEN col = 'Band_Count' THEN 'Count_'
            WHEN col = 'Band_Percent' THEN 'Percent_'
            END + CAST(StackPosition as varchar(1)) colName, value
       FROM @r
        UNPIVOT
        (
         value
         FOR col IN ([Band_Count], [Band_Percent])
        ) unpiv) src
        PIVOT
        (MAX(value)
        FOR colName IN (Count_0,Count_1,Count_2,Count_3,Count_4,Count_5,Count_6,Count_7,Count_8,Count_9,
        Percent_0,Percent_1,Percent_2,Percent_3,Percent_4,Percent_5,Percent_6,Percent_7,Percent_8,Percent_9) ) piv
```

Comment: Obviously I've confused myself way too much with all this pivoting stuff. Don't know why I didn't think of that *facepalm*

Comment: Wrap them with ISNULL(Count_0,0) + etc to deal with NULLs

Comment: or with 2008+, (SELECT SUM(value) FROM (VALUES (Count_0),(Count_1),...) s(value)) AS Count_Total.  This technique works really nicely with AVG. You don't have to count the number of non-NULL values for the divisor.